# How to get Field thread-safe Lazy initialization inside Spring Component?

Tags: java, spring

I have Spring Bean which have Map as field which must be sigleton with lazy initialization. I have code like:

```
@Component
public class Example {
    
    @Autowired
    private TestService service;
    
    public static Map<String, TestObject> map;

    public Map<String, TestObject> getMap() {
        return map;
    }
    
    private Map<String, TestObject getInstance() {
        if (map == null) {
            initMap();
        }
        return map;
    }
    
    private initMap() {
        map = new HashMap();
        map = map.put("example", service.someMethod());
    }
}
```

Is this a valid solution? If no what i need to change?
Remark: i can't use @PostConstruct or creation Map as Bean in configuration class due to common application architecture limitations

Comment: This is not threadsafe and also `map.put(service.someMethod())` is missing the 2nd parameter for `put`.

Comment: it's just the blot for example code. The main point is how to make correct thread-safe initialization

Comment: If thread-safety is one of your main doubts, I would write it explicitly in the question title or body.

Comment: If you want to keep a state of the instance in the multithreaded environment *never* use a singleton pattern.

Comment: @RomanC and what I need to use?

Comment: You need to use it constantly the stateless java bean. See [Jakarta Enterprise Beans](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Enterprise_Beans) for details.

Comment: @RomanC We could differenciate between the singleton-antipattern and a typical springbean (what is also some kind of managed singleton).

Comment: @Grim In spring we cant use a typical spring bean by multiple threads without synchronization.

Comment: @RomanC what do you mean exactly with your last comment? Aren't spring applications multi-threaded by design?

Comment: @pochopsp My last comment was addressed not to your account. Why do you ask me about it? If you have a question please, go to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). And this is last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not perfect but it is allowed by the compiler and might work (at least almost every time).

As the comments already worked out, it is not threadsafe. This means if the first two threads (two http-request) are incomming at the same time. Thread 1 see the null-map and Thread 2 see the null-map, then both Threads will call `initMap()`, call your `someMethod` twice and we may recieve two different maps throu `getInstance`.

If you can, use the singleton-functionality of your underlying CDI-framework. For Spring-CDI you could use this:

```
@Bean
@Lazy
@Scope("singleton")
public Map<String, TestObject> testSingleton(TestService testService) {
    var map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("example", testService.someMethod());
    return map;
}
```

Comment: If you do not use `<maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>` then you need the `@Qualifier("testService")`

Comment: Isn't the scope "singleton" the default for spring beans?

Comment: @pochopsp Yes singleton is the default, no need to write it in the code. I added that to point the scope out.